# Statement Coverage and Decision Coverage - I am not able conclude which is the correct answer.-Need help wrt flow chart

Tags: testing, branch, flowchart, white-box-testing

[image: Do If X<10 X=X*4 Endif X=X+1 Until X>40]

As per my knowledge of Statement coverage and branch coverage Answer should be (a) .But to be very frank still flow chart for this is not clear to me. Can someone pls help me with flow chat.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Do you want to understand the flow through the code that gives you 100 % SC and DC, or do you need a drawn flow chart? Ps. (a) is correct

Comment: Flow chart will help me better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow chart with one test case to achieve 100% statement and decision coverage.
Btw, I called it branch coverage (aka decision cov)

[image: Flow chart showing 100% statement and decision coverage]

Comment: Thank You So much. ! This gives me much better clarity to the question.

Comment: Jus one doubt why DC=1.When we have two branches from If condition. Because if we follow red edges (in flow chart these are two branches that can be achieved with Two test cases. Could you please give some clarity here with respect to Decision Coverage Please!

Comment: Glad it helped. The reason 100% DC is possible to achieve with one test is because you can re-enter the first decision gate via the last decision point, if no there.
You always aim to achieve the highest coverage with the fewest tests (effort) possible.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.